# Can I sprint while flying in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can I sprint **while flying** in Creative Mode to **move faster**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, [as lunboks explained](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32374/can-i-sprint-while-flying-in-creative-mode/32377#32377), you can sprint-fly by sprinting and then flying. I ran a couple tests, and it doesn't actually make you go faster; count in the longer setup time and it's slower.

I've put up a 100m course, where I fly straight for 100 meters. I get myself a few meters for getting a running start, so that this doesn't skew the results. [Here's the result.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ggrVV3bQds) **Make sure subtitles are on.**

For those who can't view YouTube: Once you remove the setup time, the speed is just about the same. Flying *without* sprinting oddly wins by a couple tenths (9.33 vs 9.38, roughly), but I just put it to a problem that exists between my monitor and my chain (was I perfectly centered? perfectly aligned? did I avoid swerving at all? etc.).

Comment: Changed the video to another where I actually sprint fly until the end.

Comment: BTW, if you tag your video with `yt:cc=on`, it'll [automatically enable closed captions](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140174) for everyone.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. If you start flying while sprinting, you'll be sprinting in the air. However, you can only start sprinting while on the ground.

You can verify this by paying attention to your **field of vision** — both flying and sprinting separately increase your FOV, and if you stop sprinting in mid-air, you'll notice it.

I'm not sure if this actually makes you go any faster or if the flying speed simply overrides sprinting, though if it does, it can't be much.

Answer (score 0):

The flight speed in Minecraft 1.8 is the same as, or faster than the sprinting speed on land.  So, it doesn't really matter either way; **you'll always go the same speed when flying**, from what I can tell.

Comment: -1 Missed the point of the question: Can you sprint in order to go faster than _the regular flying speed_?

Comment: @JonathanHobbs I did not, but perhaps my wording was a little off.