# How do you get to the Far Lands by flying?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you get to the Far Lands via flying?

Comment: You probably want to teleport rather than fly to do this.  [You have to travel ±12,550,825 along a horizontal axis to get there](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Far_Lands).

Answer (score 4):

The far lands on mobile exist at about +/-12,550,825 on either horizontal axis. This means that it will take an extremely long time to reach them, assuming the game doesn’t crash first.

If you want to get to the far lands, you should probably teleport there to save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: This would take you about 326 hours+ to reach via flight.

Some math on how long it would take:
Assumptions:
1. Start at 0,0.
2. Moving 100 units takes 9.355 seconds  (avg. as per [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/32394/25371) answer.)

12550825m / 100m = 125508.25
125508.25 * 9.355sec = 1174129.679 seconds
1174129.678 seconds = 326.147 hours or

**326 hours and 8 minutes and ~50 seconds**

Answer (score 0):

The Far Lands were an old PC glitch; they never existed in MCPE.